# The `mount --bind` command fail in Docker container on Ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, mount

In my application on Ubuntu 20.04, I need to execute the following commands due to mount directories for chroot:

```
% execute outside the Docker container
# cd /tmp
# mkdir a b
# mount --bind a b
```

If I do not use Docker containers, this `mount --bind` will succeed.

However, the same command will fail within a Docker container:

```
% execute in the docker container
# cd /app-data/
# mkdir a b
# mount --bind a b
mount: /app-data/b: bind /app-data/a failed.
```

I describe `cap_add: SYS_ADMIN` in `docker-compose.yaml` to launch the container.

How can I solve this problem?

For reference, here are the file system information of the execution environments:

```
% execute in the docker container
# df -T
Filesystem     Type    1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay        overlay  99014644 5453880  88511424   6% /
tmpfs          tmpfs       65536       0     65536   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     1017552       0   1017552   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda3      ext4     99014644 5453880  88511424   6% /app-data
shm            tmpfs       65536       0     65536   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     1017552       0   1017552   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs          tmpfs     1017552       0   1017552   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs          tmpfs     1017552       0   1017552   0% /sys/firmware
```

```
% execute outside the Docker container
# df -T
Filesystem     Type     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs    973876       0    973876   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs       203512     828    202684   1% /run
/dev/vda3      ext4      99014644 5453880  88511424   6% /
tmpfs          tmpfs      1017552       0   1017552   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs         5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs      1017552       0   1017552   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs          tmpfs       203508       0    203508   0% /run/user/1000
overlay        overlay   99014644 5453880  88511424   6% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/a393b5ab8ef81eb83d27565bc4695bbc899543aa075cbf7c1ccf6246ce846008/merged
shm            tmpfs        65536      16     65520   1% /var/lib/docker/containers/a4f2d1eff4b1a3ef1b8622fad4b529901fb415d77f17a31e8d9a0ed332d3819e/mounts/shm
overlay        overlay   99014644 5453880  88511424   6% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/a7453522f3e4a9f27c3cb20b0f3f4ebe75358ed9f5f909810ca18d836a601282/merged
shm            tmpfs        65536       0     65536   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/66a76b08846fbe38f633976bc8950ee414f867419310f8c612ce3aace8abfe0f/mounts/shm
```

Comment: Why do you want to run mount(8) inside the container?  Do you have any relevant application code that depends on this very specific setup, or is the question more about the Linux mechanics?

Comment: Thanks for your comments.
And thanks for making me realize that it's a strange configuration.
I've decided not to use Docker.

Answer (score 3):

A little late to answer the original requester, but I'll share the solution in case another person lands on this page as I did.

I found the solution [on this book](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=HmtgEAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT145&ots=4LXfOtiiUi&dq=mount%20%22--bind%22%20docker%20EACCES%20(Permission%20denied)&pg=PT145#v=onepage&q=mount%20%22--bind%22%20docker%20EACCES%20(Permission%20denied)&f=false). Additionally to add SYS_ADMIN capability, you need to disable AppArmor. You can run the container like this:

```
docker run -it --cap-add SYS_ADMIN --security-opt apparmor=unconfined <image>
```